# Has boost::function's default constructor the no-throw guarantee?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-function

The question is in the title. I cannot find the information in the reference documentation. I do not see why the default constructor would throw, but I need to be sure it is no-throw to correctly document my exception guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/function.html#idp15443616-bb: it explicitly states "Will not throw".

Comment: Thank you! It was quite easy in fact. I failed to see this was accessible from "Header <boost/function.hpp>" in the reference documentation.